# Showing that a set is Lebesgue Measurable in Higher Dimensions and Applying Fubini's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

I have an idea of how to proceed, but I'm suspicious that my efforts were of no use. Let $A\in\mathcal{M}$ be Lebesgue measurable, and let $g,h:A \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ be Lebesgue measurable functions with $g(x)\leq h(x) \ \forall x \in A$. With this, we define $E=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : g(x) \leq y \leq h(x)\}$. Prove that $E\in \mathcal{M^2}=\mathcal{M} \times \mathcal{M}$.

And following this, show that if $f:E \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is $\mathcal{M^2}$ measurable, then
$\displaystyle\int_Ef dm^2=\int_A(\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(x,y) \ dy) \ dx$, where $m^2=m \times m$.

For the first part, may we write $E=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : g(x) \leq y\} \cap \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : y \leq h(x)\}$
$\Rightarrow E=\bigcup\limits_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : g(x) \leq q \leq y\} \cap \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : y \leq q \leq h(x)\}$

and since $h$ and $g$ are measurable, this is a countable union of measurable sets? I don't feel so good about this reasoning, as I'm pretty sure that I would have to find a way to rewrite $E$ as cartesian product of 2 Lebesgue measurable sets (ideally, one with respect to x and the other with respect to y).
So perhaps $E=(g^{-1}[-\infty,y]\cap h^{-1}[y,\infty]) \times \{y\}$ works instead?

As for the second part, I'm not particularly sure how to use Fubini's in this scenario. I'd be very gracious for any help and guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to use that $H \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $H(x,y) = -x+y$ is continuous and thus measurable. Therefore also $$h_1(x,y)=H(g(x),y) = -g(x)+y \quad \text{and} \quad h_2(x,y)=H(h(x),y) = -h(x)+y$$ are measurable too - as functions from $A \times \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Note that we have used that the composition of measurable functions are measurable and that $$(x,y) \rightarrow (g(x),y), \quad \text{resp.} \quad (x,y) \rightarrow (h(x),y),$$ is measurable. This can checked for product sets easily. Since we only need to show measurability on a generator, this already proves the measurability according to the product-$\sigma$-algebra.

Coming back to the first  step:  We see that the set $$h^{-1}_1([0,\infty) \cap h_2^{-1}((-\infty,0]) = \{ (x,y) \in A \times \mathbb{R} : g(x) \le y \le h(x)\} $$
is measurable.

The second part can be shown by Fubini's theorem as follows: We have
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) 1_{E}(x,y) \, \lambda^2(x,y) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y) 1_{E}(x,y) \,dy \, dx \\
&=\int_{A} \int_{[g(x),h(x)]} f(x,y) 1_{E}(x,y) \,dy \, dx. 
\end{align}
In the last line we have used that $g(x) \le h(x)$ for all $x \in A$.

Comment: Very clever use of $h(x,y)$ for the first part! Thank you very much.

Comment: Just a question: how is it that we are allowed to defined $h$ as you did? It seems to me that you have only showed that the statement holds for your particular choice of $h$. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry! I mixed up the notation. $H$ is a auxiliary function - I have changed the notation and call it now with a capital $h$. I have added some more comments in my answer. In particular, why $h_1$ and $h_2$ are measurable.

Comment: @p4sch thanks for the clarification. The only thing I’m still confused about is, how do we rid ourselves of the characteristic function in the integrand (on the last line)? It’s clear to me why the first one is the integral over $E$. Does this just follow from the fact that the integral evaluates to $0$ off $E$?

Comment: We have by definition $(x,y) \in E$ if and only if $x in A$ and $y \in [g(x),h(x)]$. Thus, I have only rewritten the last integral.